# Help understanding purpose of this schottky diode and resistors in MAXIM DS2777 typical configuration

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit

I am looking to design a pack-side gauge/protection IC and so am looking at the MAXIM DS2777 IC ([datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS2775-DS2778.pdf)).

In their datasheet page 10 is the typical application circuit. I lack understanding with parts of the circuit and was hoping for someone to provide an explanation:

1. What is the purpose of the Schottky Diode on pin PLS?
2. What is the purposes of the 1k resistor on the PLS, as a resistor for a internal voltage divider?
3. What is the purpose of the 1k resistor on Vin2 and Vin1? I don't see what they do at all, the input resistance of these pins are 15Mohm so the 1k here won't really achieve anything (negligible impact to current flow and also very low voltage drop)
4. Whats the purpose of the 150ohm resistor on Vdd? That doesn't seem to be necessary either..

Thanks in advance!

[image: Typical application circuit]

Comment: For the resistors, their purpose is probably to limit current in the event of failure. Not sure about the diode. I am too lazy to read the datasheet. I assume you actually read the datasheet since you are working on a design with this part, right? Did they not offer an explanation for the diode?

Comment: No they didn't and so the part confused me.. Since they also didn't say what they want in terms of thermal, peak current etc... The explanation of the external resistors limiting maximum current make sense though, thanks for that!

Comment: Weird. Check if there is an evaluation board available (with a BOM) and you can use the same part they used there. Also see if you can contact applications engineering to answer the question. Or maybe someone here will know and answer. All these companies used to have good applications engineering departments. Not sure if they still do.

Comment: Their eval kit doesn't have a BOM and infact just lists that part as Schottky..... I assume that just means its a standard part (maybe I will just use one that can sink a bit more current than the standard just in case). A lot of these typical application diagrams don't really explain what the parts are for and why the selected value (except for some critical pieces).

Comment: Varies from vendor to vendor. I normally don't consider any Maxim parts (due to availability issues and high price), so I haven't spent much time reading their datasheets. Linear has amazing datasheets. Usually their parts are too expensive, but I read the datasheets because they are so good. Usually vendors supply the BOM to their EVM, because the whole point is to simplify the process of designing in the part. It is incredibly stupid for them to not supply a BOM to their EVM, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

- What is the purpose of the Schottky Diode on pin PLS?

  - V_PLS has absolute maximum rating of -0.3V to 18V. The shottky is there to protect the pin. Without it, the PLS input may see too negative of an input under some circumstances, for example if connector is not plugged in all the way so that PK- is disconnected, and both FETs are open, and there are 5V pull-ups on SDA and SCL.
- What is the purposes of the 1k resistor on the PLS, as a resistor for a internal voltage divider?

  - This limits current when the batter is very discharged: "When a charger is detected and VPLS > VIN2, the DS2775–DS2778 provide a current-limited
    recovery charge path (IRC) from PLS to VDD to gently
    charge severely depleted cells.". Plus protection (see below).
- What is the purpose of the 1k resistor on Vin2 and Vin1?

  - Battery protection. If chip fails or goes to latch-up mode for some reason such that Vin is connected to ground/Vcc, the whole thing will not catch fire. It also protects from shorted pins, for example due to tin whiskers.
- Whats the purpose of the 150ohm resistor on Vdd?

  - Same reason. If pass transistor in internal regulator fails, the whole thing will not catch fire.

Comment: Can you help elaborate on how this recovery charge path works and how the current is limited by the resistor (on PLS)?

Thanks!

Comment: "Undervoltage" section (pg 14) describes "recovery charge path", which sounds like a linear constant current regulator. The I_RC value (last line in pg 3) specifies 3-13mA, and max input of 15V. So it seems the resistor is not actually required for current regulation? One idea is that without resistor IC may have to dissipate more than 100mW; while if the resistor is present most of the power will be dissipated there.